# jQuery - using user input values in text template - best practice?

Tags: jquery, text, input

I have a form where users input several dozen values to generate a report. The desired text output has a specific format, so in order to generate it I've been doing this:

```
var textoutput = "The house on " + $("#usercontent1").val() + " has " 
+ $("#usercontent2").val() + " bathrooms and ";
+ $("#usercontent3").val() + "bedrooms.";
```

etc. Is there a more efficient way of doing this so that it's more readable?
 Currently this block of text is a few hundred lines long given the number of input fields and getting a bit unwieldy.

Answer (score 0):

How about a **for loop**...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

console.log('1. Document is ready.');

// Run the App.
runApplication();

});

// We create a variable called runApplication and assign it a function runApplication()
var runApplication = function runApplication() {

console.log('1.1 runApplication() function called.');

// We make a reference to all element inputs of type text inside form1..
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#form1 input[type=text]');

// then we create a Global string variable to append stuff to...
var final_string = '';

// then for each and every punt of type text found inside form1...
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    // if it's really somthing other than nothing....
    if(elements[i] = true) {
        // append current input text value in the lopp to variable final_string
        final_string = final_string + elements[i].value + ' ';
        console.log(elements[i].value);
    }
}

// output final_string with all input text values...
// ..joined together by the for loop.
console.log(final_string);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" value="1">
<input type="text" value="2">
<input type="text" value="3">
<input type="text" value="4">
<input type="text" value="5">
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, one of the limitations is that each field may have different text before or after the user input in order to accommodate the sentence structure.